# Activating and deactivating a solid state relay with 3v and 2v, respectively

Tags: solid-state-relay

I have a normally closed solid state relay (link to datasheet below), that I would like to activate with 3V and deactivate with 2V. The load is a 24V 100mA LED. How should I go about this?

Datasheet for SSR: https://docs.rs-online.com/4030/0900766b81471bd5.pdf

Please let me know if I should provide more information.

Comment: You mean it should turn on when a certain voltage goes above 3V and then go off when it goes below 2V?

Comment: No, it should turn on when the input voltage is 3V and turn off when the voltage is 2V.

Comment: And what happens in between?  Anyway sounds like you want to read up on comparators.  If you want to actually hold state you may benefit from introducing a cheap MCU where you can apply some software filtering to the decision.

Comment: Yes, what happens in between?

Comment: Thank you, comparators sounds like a good idea. I have measured the voltage with a multimeter, and it just seems to change quickly.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I have measured the voltage with a multimeter, and it just seems to change quickly."* What voltage? What kind of input signal are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. "The voltage" is the input voltage, with which I need to activate the solid state relay. I expect it to be either 2v or 3v. The source of the voltage is a power LED output of a PC. Does that make sense?

Comment: why don't you use the power supply output or a USB port power to turn on the SSR?

Comment: Great ideas. But sadly I do not have access to the power supply and the only available USB ports are of the always-on type.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments and suggestions. For now I'm using an Arduino Nano, but I may use a comparator or schmitt trigger later on.

Answer (score 0):

It is similar and I have a model for it. The result will be the same as yours. What you can use for driving is a CMOS Schmitt trigger (HC14, AC14 ...).

[image: opto]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the solution 3 volt = On and 2 volt = Off you need two functions:

**1, Schmitt-trigger** (https://components101.com/articles/schmitt-trigger-introduction-working-applications) and

**2. Flip Flop** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) that will keep the state on the "solid state relay".

The Schmitt-trigger and Flip Flop can be realized with discrete components, logic ICs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400-series_integrated_circuits) or a MCU (Micro Controller Unit).